# Jmeter threads slow to start

Tags: jmeter

Excuse my basic jMeter knowledge.

My script has 5 thread groups, one with two threads, three with 1 thread and then the final group with 30 threads.  When the final group runs it runs first for 1 thread then when that thread has completed it will run the 30 threads concurrently including that thread 1.

Any clues on how I can get that thread group to kick off with all 30 threads when it starts?  Instead of initially with just 1 thread.

Thread group config

[image]

Test plan config

[image]

Inside the thread group in question there is a double nesting of loop controllers, which seem to work correctly.

Hope you can help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly then in my opinion, there is an option in the Test Plan which says Run Thread Groups consecutively-- Uncheck the same and then execute your run, it should work..!!

Answer (score 0):

You most probably checked by error "Run thread Groups consecutively" option in [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan):

[image: Run Thread Groups consecutively]

Comment: Thanks but I want to run the thread groups consecutively but the last thread group all threads don't start at the same time.  The first thread finished then all 30 threads start up.  I just want all threads to start at the same time, in that thread group, not all thread groups to start at the same time.

Comment: I added images to the original post for thread group config and test plan config.

Comment: Can you show an overview of your test and show what makes you think 1 thread of last group starts and only when it ends all others are started ? From your configuration , 30 threads  should rampup from 0 to 30 threads in 1 second

Comment: I use the 'Active threads over time' chart to see this happening.  Plus I have dashboards on the backend system and see this behavior there also.

Comment: I see your Thread Group has only 1 iteration, do you have a Loop Controller in it ?

Comment: Yes it does have a loop controller.  The thread group has two sub simple controllers then under one of those there is a loop controller.